# Connecting Python notebook to MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter, pymysql

How can I connect a MySQL database to my Jupyter notebook to execute queries using Python notebook?

My code:

```
import pymysql
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=dsn_hostname, port=dsn_port, user=dsn_uid, passwd=dsn_pwd, db=dsn_database)
```

After establishing connection how can I start executing queries?

Comment: "After I connect how can I connect?" What?

Comment: Sorry. Edited the question

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896206/4999991)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all written in the documentation: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymysql.cursorsenter 
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='user_name',
                         password='password',
                         db='name_of_database',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```