# Connect to MySQL db from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebooks to learn Python. I would like to connect to a MySQL db hosted locally hosted through MAMP. How would I approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Answer (score 16):

```
import os
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

host = os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST')
port = os.getenv('MYSQL_PORT')
user = os.getenv('MYSQL_USER')
password = os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD')
database = os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE')

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host=host,
    port=int(port),
    user=user,
    passwd=password,
    db=database,
    charset='utf8mb4')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE",
    conn)
df.tail(10)
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have MySQL installed (instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/b351fe7686de19a4c91d3e0b4c91080a) for macOS using HomeBrew), you need to:

- Install `pip3 install ipython-sql`
- `pip3 install mysqlclient`

now you should be able to run these cells and get pretty-printed HTML output:

```py
# %%
%load_ext sql

# %%
%sql mysql+mysqldb://<user>:<password>@localhost/<dataBase>

# %%
%%sql

SELECT *
FROM <table>;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import pymysql

import pandas as a

conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=int(3306),user='root',passwd='YOUR_PASSWORD',db='YOUR_DATABASENAME')

df=a.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM 'YOUR_TABLENAME' ",conn)

print(df)
```

Comment: maybe you could comment on how your code solves the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You can use the [MySQL Connector](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python) library. Simply install it using pip, and then you can use it to interact with your database. See the sample code below:

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="mamp",
   passwd=""
)

print(db)
```

Comment: What about using Scala in Notebook? Thanks. I am having trouble with Scala: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154372/com-mysql-jdbc-driver-not-found-in-spark2-scala, thank you very much.